# How to load a local file for a clojurescript test

Tags: clojurescript

I am writing some `cljs.test` tests for a clojurescript library and have some `JSON` test data I would like to load in.

I'm unsure what function I can use to load the data from files local to the project.

I'm using [lein-doo](https://github.com/bensu/doo) as the test runner, initially with a nodejs configuration, ideally I would like to load files in an agnostic manner if possible, but I'd be fine with a nodejs-specific answer.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34557616/597473 - it covers loading a local file in CLJS running in NodeJS.

Comment: Ahh thank you, have posted an answer to complete this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Piotrek's link I have come up with the following nodejs-only function that accomplishes this:

```
(defn node-slurp [path]
    (let [fs (nodejs/require "fs")]
        (.readFileSync fs path "utf8")))
```

(Node documentation: [File System - readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options))

Comment: This gives me the error: `No such namespace: nodejs, could not locate nodejs.cljs, nodejs.cljc, or JavaScript source providing "nodejs"`

Comment: Use `js/require`, rather than `nodejs/require`.